# How to add AMD/legacy dependency (leaflet) with sub dependencies in requirejs

Tags: requirejs, leaflet

I installed a AMD module called leaflet and successfully using it as "L".
Next I need a plugin called leaflet.draw but I get confused about the dependencies. Consider the following code:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'bower_components',
    paths: {
        leaflet: 'leaflet/dist/leaflet-src',
        leafletdraw: 'leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw-src'
        ...

requirejs(["leaflet", "leafletdraw"], function(L, leafletdraw) {
    var map = new L.Map('map');
    ...
```

This gives a referenceError: L is not defined at Leaflet.draw.js:4. So I guess it needs the leaflet (L) as a dependency, right? I then tried to add it in the shim config:

```
shim: {
    leafletdraw: {
        deps: 'leaflet'
    }
}
```

This results in a "Invalid require call". So my question is: How do I properly require a plugin with subdependencies?

- The modules are installed with "bower install leaflet" and "bower
  install leaflet-draw" respectivily. But im not sure if leaflet-draw
  is AMD enabled. Why isnt that stated in repos docs? Can I assume it
  is enabled by default?
- This is what I try to achive:
  http://codepen.io/osmbuildings/pen/LVJzWw, but with requirejs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: shim leaflet itself, and let it export 'L'. Then putting the deps in plugins will work. My full config:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'bower_components',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery/dist/jquery.min',
        leaflet: 'http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet',
        'leaflet-draw': 'http://cdn.osmbuildings.org/Leaflet.draw/0.2.0/leaflet.draw',        
        OSMBuildings: ['http://cdn.osmbuildings.org/OSMBuildings-Leaflet']    
    },    
    shim: {
        leaflet: {
            exports: 'L'
        },
        'leaflet-draw': {
            deps: ['leaflet']
        },        
        OSMBuildings: {
            deps: ['leaflet'],
            exports: 'OSMBuildings'
        }
    }
});

requirejs(["jquery", "leaflet", "leaflet-draw", "OSMBuildings"], function($, L, dummy, OSMBuildings) {
    var map = new L.Map('map');
```